# Getline doesn't work in a loop

Tags: c++, buffer, getline

I am trying to use

```
getline(cin, x)
```

in a for loop.

However, the first time it runs, it just returns a blank line.

There are many questions like this, and I have tried both

```
cin.ignore() and cin.clear()
```

as suggested and even tried using one more getline in between to clear the buffer but to no avail.

Is there any other trick involved?

Thanks

```
char x;
cin >> x;


int y, z;
cin >> y >> z;

    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>max(), '\n');

for (int a = 0; a < z; a++){
   for(int b = 0; b < y; b++){
       string hello;
       getline (cin, hello);

       etc etc
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Show your code! Chances are it means that a newline character is still left in the input stream.

Comment: Updated! Nice username 1234567890

Comment: Thanks for updating. Where are you doing the `cin.ignore/clear` call in your code?

Comment: I have tried it after cin >> y >> z, and before I declare string hello;

Comment: `etc etc` is not valid C++. Show your [_testcase_](http://sscce.org).

Comment: We cannot actually see how you are calling ignore() which is the key one here. The "clear" is needed if the parsing into y or z fails.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as I suggested in the comments, you will have a newline character left in `cin`. So when `getline` is first called, it just reads this empty line. The reason the newline character is still there is because extracting from `cin` to an `int` (as in `cin >> y >> z`) will not extract the following newline. `getline` does, however, extract the newline.

One solution is to use `ignore` after extracting into `y` and `z`:

```
cin >> y >> z;
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

This actually also ignores any other extraneous characters up until the newline character.

Comment: +1 I know this is the solution, but can you explain to the OP why his `cin.ignore()`/`cin.clear()` did not work?

Comment: The clear() has no effect, it clears error flags and I'm assuming there aren't any here. That would happen if y and z were not parsed properly i.e. the strings were not ints.

The ignore needs to take the right parameters and I guess he didn't pass them.

Comment: Also, what does the first parameter of cin.ignore() mean? Do I need to put in an arbitrarily large number or calculate it some other way? I am still getting the error

Comment: @user2162690 `std::cin.ignore()` takes two optional arguments - the number of characters to discard and the delimiter where discarding will stop. The default amount to discard is `1` and the delimiter by default is the end of the stream.

Comment: I am using namespace std; so cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>max(), '\n'); gives me errors that  ‘numeric_limits’ was not declared in this scope, expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token, and no matching function for call to ‘max()’. I tried with just cin.ignore('\n') and it still doesn't work

Comment: @user2162690 You have to include the header `<limits>`.

Comment: And then what is streamsize set to? It says expected primary-expression before ‘max’

Comment: @0x499602D2 It's hard to say why their `cin.ignore()` didn't work without seeing how they used it. But thanks for answering his commments.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the original post. I'm not understanding this concept of streamsize and what exactly is being limited

Comment: @user2162690 Looks like you missed the `::` before `max()` - `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()`.

Comment: @user2162690 `std::streamsize` is an integer type that can represent the size of a stream. `std::numeric_limit<some_type>::max()` gives you the maximum value that `some_type` can store. So what we're getting is the maximum size of a stream! Passing that to `ignore` says "I want to extract the maximum possible characters from `cin` until I hit a `\n`."

Comment: Okay that makes sense. It still does not work, but on the bright side I learned something.

Comment: @user2162690 What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What are you supplying as input, and what unwanted behavior are you experiencing?

Comment: Basically the first getline in the loop still gives me a blank line. As input I'm supplying a normal string of letters, and when I assert if those letters are actually the letters I need, it exits because the string is blank. However, later on if I cin a char and then getline, it works.

Comment: @user2162690 Can you give us a full example of your program?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation on ignore:](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)

Passed with no parameters, it will only ignore the next char. I guess that there are other characters before the first newline?